# What is that thing that no one's been out to collect?

Tags: men-in-black, men-in-black-international

In [*Men in Black: International* (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_in_Black:_International), before they meet a pawn and its queen, Molly and Agent H are about to enter an old antique shop:

> Molly: Looks like a couple days' worth. **No one's been out to collect**.

What is that thing that no one's been out to collect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of parcels that have been dropped off at the front door of the curio shop.

[image]

No one's been out to collect **the parcels**.

Answer (score 3):

The novelisation clears this up, there were a couple of days worth of Amazon parcels at the door.

> Em noticed the stack of Amazon packages piled beside the door; many of them had addresses located on other planets and even galaxies. "Couple days' worth," she said, "No one's been out to collect."

Comment: Eww. Novelisations. Who reads those?